# Adapt the panel reducing the screen, when inside panel there is a word with 'pre' html tag

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this kind of problem with my angularJS app. 
When I reduce the window of the browser, accordingly I reduce a panel with a very long word inside (like 20 char), which I have code with 'pre' html tag to not break the line. At some point the word 'escape' from panel and the effect is very very ugly. Is there a way 'to notify' to the panel that my word must not start a new line and avoid that the word escape from panel?
Thank you in advance.

That is my code

```
    <div class="panel-body" uib-collapse="isCollapsedHeader">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-lg-2 label-margin"> Data riferimento </label>
                <div class="col-lg-1 right-col-margin">{{fondo.dataRif}}</div>
                <label class="col-lg-2 label-margin"> Chiave IB </label>
                <div class="col-lg-7 i9fontPre right-col-margin">{{fondo.chiave}}</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

and my css

```
.i9fontPre {
    white-space:pre; 
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}

.row label.label-margin { 
    margin: 0px 0px 1px 0px !important;
}

.row  .right-col-margin{ 
    margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: can you use `overflow: hidden;` to keep it from escaping the panel?  If you post your code we can probably give you a more robust answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word;` to break it up.  Here is a working example:

```css
#box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <pre>
    Reeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaaaalllyyyylongword
  </pre>
</div>
```

You can apply the `word-wrap` to either the `<pre>` or its container element.

Answer (score 0):

Please try html5 wbr tag for break long word.

Example:

```
<p>This is a veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryvery**<wbr>**longwordthatwillbreakatspecific<wbr>placeswhenthebrowserwindowisresized.</p>
```

Plz check below link for solution

https://jsfiddle.net/1pwmnq3L/

Comment: I can't decide where break the word because I don't know anything about these long words. They came from server call.

Comment: Hello Lorenzo

If word comes from server end, So you force fully hide your long word with ellipsis Property.

Answer (score 0):

As per i comment on your question of hiding your text from css3 Ellipsis property. Please check below link.

```css
div{ width:120px; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis;}
```

```html
<div>
  logggggggggggggggggggggggggggggworddddddddddddddd
</div>
```